# Solaar: How to scroll through desktops

Tags: kubuntu, solaar

I want to be able to scroll through desktops from wherever my mouse might be, and not be limited to having to scroll when hovering over the task manager.

Since I have a logitech mouse with a thumb wheel, I tried Solaar. I've set-up the following: a test on `thumb_wheel_down` and an action using `xdotool`, which from the terminal is able to switch between desktops.

However, scrolling does nothing after these rules are applied. What do I miss?

I've checked using `xev` to see if the inputs are registered, here I can see mouse button 6 and 7 being activated on scroll.

[image: Solaar rule configuration]
The Rules

[image: Overview page Solaar]
The overview page

EDIT:
I have now also changed the setting to set up Thumb Wheel Diversion, as that was a requirement. Though the Execute does not trigger the desktop change. If I change the command to `nautilus` I do get an execution, what are the requirements for an Execute command?

Comment: Include information about your Ubuntu version in your question: use "edit". Note that xdotool only works on Xorg.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with next approach
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf2nv.png)

1. Add rule => Test, thumb_wheel_down and insert below action for go to next workspace. On my PC when I click super + Page Down I go to previous workspace for example.